# Delete a Node from a Linked List using key

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I want to delete a node from the linked list. The linked list contains the following type of data(contains data having spaces)

```
aa 1 1 1 1

bb 2 2 2 2 

ab 3 3 3 3

cc 4 4 4 4 

dd 5 5 5 5
```

The problem is my code is only deleting the last node i have created with dd 5 5 5 5 and nothing else!
Please read my code and suggest me any solution why it is happening to me?

```
public Node del(String key){
        Node p=first;

        for(Node c=first;c!=null;c=c.next)

        {
           if(c.data.startsWith(key)){
              if(c.next==null){
                  return null;
              }else{
                   p=c;
              }
              if(c==first)
                  first=first.next;
              else
                  p.next=c.next;
              return c;
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you show the code for your `Node` class ?

Comment: try using `c.data.contains(key)`

Comment: I wonder how does it delete the last node. If `c` points to the last node (`c.next==null`) and it is the node with the required key (`c.data.startsWith(key)`), it will return null but will not change the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(currentnode=start; currentnode!=null; currentnode=currentnode.delnext){

        if(currentnode.deldata.startsWith(mykey)){

                        if(currentnode==start)
                            start=start.delnext;
                        else
                            prevnode.delnext=currentnode.delnext;

                        currentnode.deldata=null;

        }

        prevnode=currentnode;
    }

    }
```

This code will work like a charm I have corrected my code ! thanks God

Answer (score 0):

In the iteration you need to maintain the current node (`c`) and the previous ('p'). And then if you find that `c` has the key you are looking for, then set `p.next = c.next`. This will remove c form the list.
Then test the code for empty list, list with one element, and list with 2 elements, because in these special cases you need to handle the removal differently.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. The only case that actually works is to remove the first element of the list.

I think you learn more by finding out the right solution than when I just give it to you. Try to make a sketch of the list on paper and observe which nodes the variables `p` and `c` refer to as your program runs.

It may also be helpful to view the execution in the debugger while single stepping through the program.

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic as following:

```
public Node del(String key)
{
    Node p = null;

    for(Node c=first;c!=null;p=c;c=c.next)
    {
       if(c.data.startsWith(key))
       {
           if(c==first)
               first=first.next;
           else
               p.next=c.next;

           c.next = null;
           return c;
       }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you want to delete a node in linked list, you should have a reference to it's previous node. `p` is the reference maintained one node before the current node `c`. Check how the `for` loop is modified.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssss Sirrrr !!! i have no words to say though i get a point from your code so GOD BLESS YOU YOU GIVE ME A HINT

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem (there some others but I'll focus on the one you asked for) is that p always points to the first link. When you found the key you do `p.next = c.next` so if your item is found at the last link than `first.next` will point to the last link skipping all other valid links.

for example :

> 1->2->3->4->5

if I look for **key=4** than after your code the list will look like :

> 1->5